# After Removing Gnome3, Gnome couldn't load!

Tags: 11.04, gnome, uninstall, re-installation

After Uninstalling Gnome3, i reboot computer and appeared Proxy user below mine and didn't know its pass. After i logged in with my name, terminal just opened. Then i tried  installing ubuntu desktop but it couldn't fetch repos so i couldn't. I updated the sources.list and removed old 10.10 ones but it didn't work also, cause i couldn't connect the internet due to proxy i guess. I tried many solutions similar to mine. But i couldn't solve it. I hope they didn't effect the system badly. I just want to know,

Is there any way to fix up the system without reinstalling Ubuntu or without loss of user data?

Comment: Oh, this one is simple. Just restore the backup of your system you made before installing unsupported software. :)

Answer (score 1):

If you have the live CD of 11.04 or can get one, put it into the tray, then run the following:

```
sudo apt-cdrom add #this will add the CD to the sources list
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
```

Comment: thanks mate. I fixed up with clean install after backup.